# How to remove file name from url using .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have follwoing url's

```
http://127.1.1.1/mysite/username/admin
```

I want to display like this url

```
http://127.1.1.1/mysite/admin
```

Here 'username' is file name.

How it can be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Store this .htaccess to `http://127.1.1.1/mysite/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on /mysite/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ username/$1 [r=301,L]
```

`http://127.1.1.1/mysite/admin` -> `http://127.1.1.1/mysite/username/admin`
`http://127.1.1.1/mysite/admin.php?some=value` -> `http://127.1.1.1/mysite/username/admin.php?some=value`

username.php

```
RewriteEngine on /mysite/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ username.php?requested-file=$1 [r=301,L]
```

`http://127.1.1.1/mysite/admin` -> `http://127.1.1.1/mysite/username.php?requested-file=admin`

Comment: but admin is not file name.. it's user name.. eg: thomas,rio,pitend